# Mongodb c# driver: view MQL bson query generated from linq

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, mongodb-.net-driver

Using the latest version (2.14) is there any way to view the bson query document generated by a specific linq query?

I want to do this for two reasons:

1. debugging queries
2. copying them to run in another mongo client like compass

I know I can enable profiling, but I can't see any way to guarantee a query you find in the mongo log was generated by a specific line of code or query. Plus it's a bit long winded to do it via profiling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 options to get MQL query from LINQ request:

1. Install lately released query [analyzer](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/article/introducing-mongodb-analyzer-dotnet/). As I know it may not be 100% accurate if you use global static serialization configuration.
2. Configure `CommandStartedEvent` event [subscriber](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.14/reference/driver_core/events/) and analyze `Command` document. Pay attention that you may need to remove some technical fields like `$db` (maybe few more) that might not be parsed by compass correctly, you will see it in the exception message if any.

Answer (score 2):

@dododo answer is the right and best one, I'm just adding some code here which works for option 2:

```
    var settings = MongoClientSettings.FromUrl(new MongoUrl(@"mongodb://localhost"));
    settings.ClusterConfigurator = builder =>
    {
        builder.Subscribe<CommandStartedEvent>(x =>
        {
            var queryDocument = x.Command;
        });
    };

    var client =  new MongoClient(settings);
```