# Creating MongoDB like update document in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am trying to create a `MongoDB` like update document in my C# code. This is not used to update the `MongoDB` but the API I am using expects the data in this format.

I tried using `MongoDB.Driver` NuGet package and tried to create the document like this.

```
class Program
{
    class MyTest
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } = String.Empty;
        public string Description { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var v = Builders<MyTest>.Update
            .Set(t => t.Name , "TestName")
            .Set(t => t.Description ,"TestDescription");

    }
}
```

This code compiles and runs. But I need the output in string format. Something like:

```
$set: {Name:"TestName",Description:"TestDescription"}
```

Is there anyway to get a string representation like that?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70958926/mongodb-c-sharp-driver-view-mql-bson-query-generated-from-linq/70973653#70973653

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
var output = v.Render(BsonSerializer.LookupSerializer<MyTest>(), new BsonSerializerRegistry());
```

This will render the **Update** document to a **BsonValue**.

Comment: better to do the following:  `var registry = BsonSerializer.SerializerRegistry; var serializer = registry.GetSerializer<MyTest>();   var rendered = v.Render(serializer, registry);`

Comment: @dododo LookupSerializer() method does exactly what you wrote.

Comment: Awesome..works as expected.

Comment: @RaduHatos, no, it doesn't. In your case, you ignore predefined serializers