# Rendering MongoDB update document with nested objects in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am trying to create a `MongoDB` update document in my C# application. I used to `MongoDB.Driver` and was able to do for a simple class.

```
 class MyTest
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } 
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

  public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var v1 = Builders<MyTest>.Update
            .Set(t => t.Name, "TestName")
            .Set(t => t.Description, "TestDescription");

        var output = v1.Render(BsonSerializer.LookupSerializer<MyTest>(), new BsonSerializerRegistry()).ToString();
}
```

This produced expected output

```
{ "$set" : { "Name" : "TestName", "Description" : "TestDescription" } }
```

However, if I have a nested structure like this:

```
 class MyInnerClass
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }
    class MyTest
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } 
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public List<MyInnerClass> InnerClasses { get;} = new List<MyInnerClass>();
    }

   
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var v1 = Builders<MyTest>.Update
            .Set(t => t.Name, "TestName")
            .Set(t => t.Description, "TestDescription")
            .Set(t => t.InnerClasses[0].Id, "TestId");

        var output = v1.Render(BsonSerializer.LookupSerializer<MyTest>(), new BsonSerializerRegistry()).ToString();
}
```

I get the exception when doing `Render`:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to determine the
> serialization information for t => t.InnerClasses.get_Item(0).Id.'

How to do this correctly?

Note that, I want the string representation of the update for my API call and not updating any real DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
        BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<MyTest>((b) =>
        {
            b.AutoMap();
            b.MapField(f=>f.InnerClasses);
        });

        var v1 = Builders<MyTest>.Update
                   .Set(t => t.Name, "TestName")
                   .Set(t => t.Description, "TestDescription")
                   .Set(t => t.InnerClasses[0].Id, "TestId");

        var output = v1.Render(BsonSerializer.LookupSerializer<MyTest>(), new BsonSerializerRegistry()).ToString();
```

another option, you can simply provide a raw query like:

```
        var v1 = Builders<MyTest>.Update
                   .Set(t => t.Name, "TestName")
                   .Set(t => t.Description, "TestDescription")
                   .Set("InnerClasses.0._id", "TestId");

        var registry = BsonSerializer.SerializerRegistry;
        var serializer = registry.GetSerializer<MyTest>();
        var output = v1.Render(serializer, registry).ToString();
```

Comment: also, as I suggested to you in some previous question, you can look at my answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70958926/mongodb-c-sharp-driver-view-mql-bson-query-generated-from-linq/70973653#70973653 to get more ways to do it in particular to look at query analyzer nuget.

Comment: This works. However when I do `unset`, I get the value 1 in JSON serialized string. Is that expected?

Comment: which particular query do you see?