# What are the best practises to handle Audit in a NOSQL database like mongo

Tags: mongodb, nosql

What are the best practises to handle Audit in a NOSQL database like mongo. Audit of selected set of documents and selected set of fields only.

Comment: not sure which particular audit you mean, but if it's about commands sent to server, then you can do it via: 1. configure logging https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/csharp/current/fundamentals/logging/ or 2. event subscription (see #2 in my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70958926/mongodb-c-sharp-driver-view-mql-bson-query-generated-from-linq/70973653#70973653)

Comment: note: drivers for other languages than c# has similar concepts