# How to get the fields/options of an aggregation command from a MongoDB IPipelineStageDefinition in C#?

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-.net-driver

I need to verify in a unit test that the [`AggregateAsync`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.22/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollection_1_AggregateAsync__1_1.htm) method received a specific aggregation command that is represented via a [`PipelineDefinition<BsonDocument, BsonDocument>`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.22/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_PipelineDefinition_2.htm) instance.
The command is [`$collStats`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/collStats/) with the additional field/option [`storageStats`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/collStats/#storagestats-document).
How can I check that the pipeline contains exactly this command, including the additional field?

I can get the [individual stages](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.22/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_IPipelineStageDefinition.htm) of the pipeline with [`Stages`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.22/html/P_MongoDB_Driver_PipelineDefinition_2_Stages.htm), so I can verify that there is only a single stage (containing the command above) and then get this stage:

```
PipelineDefinition<BsonDocument, BsonDocument> pipeline = ...; // obtained from some callback
IPipelineStageDefinition stage = pipeline.Stages.Single();
```

Now, I can easily check if this stage contains the `$collStats` command with [`OperatorName`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.22/html/P_MongoDB_Driver_IPipelineStageDefinition_OperatorName.htm):

```
if (stage.OperatorName == "$collStats")
{
    // check for additional "storageStats" field
}
```

But how can I check whether this command also contains the field `storageStats`?
Unfortunately, there does not seem to be a similar property like `OperatorFields`.
The only solution I currently found is to serialize the stage, and then check whether this serialized representation contains the specific field:

```
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization;

BsonDocument command = stage.Render(
    BsonSerializer.SerializerRegistry.GetSerializer<BsonDocument>(),
    BsonSerializer.SerializerRegistry).Document;
BsonDocument fields = command.GetValue("$collStats").ToBsonDocument();

if (fields.Contains("storageStats"))
{
    // finally ...
}
```

This feels way too complex and like the wrong way to do.
Is there a simpler solution which I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To validate a MQL query, you have to render it. The reason for this is that a pipeline can be created in different ways and not always it's based on already rendered BsonDocument.
So it might be rendering a stage as in your code above or Render the whole pipeline (which basically the same):

```
        var registry = BsonSerializer.SerializerRegistry;
        var serializer = registry.GetSerializer<BsonDocument>();
        var renderedStages = pipeline.Render(serializer, registry).Documents
```

You may also configure event subscriber on `CommandStartedEvent` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70973653/9492730)), but I doubt a server call is what you need here

Comment: Hmm, I guess I have to to that then. But why is there an `OperatorName` property? This is also part of the pipeline (which can be created in different ways as you said) and yet, I have direct access. Seems like the MongoDB .NET API is a bit inconsistent here: "Hey, you want the command name? Sure, here is a nice property. You also want its fields? Sorry, we can't do that!" Rather weird in my opinion, but it is what it is.

Comment: 'why is there an OperatorName property' - it's used internally, in some cases you have to know what is the stage about without rendering it